# Specify font color in R within R2PPT?

Tags: r, text, colors, powerpoint

I am trying to see if the R package [R2PPT](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R2PPT/index.html) can allow you to add text with a specific color to a slide.  For example, I can begin a powerpoint file with the following code:

```
require(R2PPT)

# Initialize and add title slide
myPres<-PPT.Init(visible=TRUE, method="RDCOMClient")
myPres<-PPT.AddTitleSlide(myPres,title="How to make PowerPoint from R!")

# Add another text slide
myPres <- PPT.AddTextSlide(myPres, title = "Test Title", text = "test text")
```

However, I am unable to specify the color of the `title` or `text` (e.g. setting the title color to green).  I could specify some font or font size with the other optional arguments but nothing for color.  Is there some function in R that could specify the color of some text output perhaps?  And yes, this scenario is restricted to powerpoint.

Comment: You might want to ping Wayne Jones about it; the email's listed on the page you've linked to.

Comment: You might look at David Gohel's ReporteRs package.  It can create PowerPoint files and has many formatting capabilities.